# Underline does not display in fraction. Mathjax bug?

Tags: bug, mathjax

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2087105/2582) the underline below $k$ in the exponent in the definition of $\binom nk$ cannot be seen. It took `\displaystyle` for it to appear.

I can reproduce the issue here as well. Compare this: $\binom nk = \frac{n^\underline{k}}{k!}$, with this:
$$\binom nk = \frac{n^\underline{k}}{k!}$$

The code is the same,

```
\binom nk = \frac{n^\underline{k}}{k!}
```

but in the first instance the underline is not appearing. For reference, this is what I'm seeing:

[image: screenshot]

My browser is Chromium 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit), and other users reported the same issue.

Comment: I'm running Chrome 55.0.2883.87 on Windows 10. It might be an issue with the MathJax math renderer (MathJax context menu ⇒ Math Settings ⇒ Math Renderer). With [HTML-CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5p21.png) I don't see the underline in the inline equation. With [Common HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x2NA.png) and Preview HTML I see the underline, though it's positioned horribly. With [SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WGd5.png) I see it, faintly as it is somewhat poorly positioned.

Comment: I'm running MacOS X 10.11.5 and Firefox 50.1.0 and using HTML-CSS. Everything looks fine here.

Comment: I am running Arch Linux (64bit) with Firefox 50.1.0, HTML-CSS, and it looks the same. But I had to use zoom to actually see that the underline is missing on the inline formula.

Comment: Interestingly, without zoom if I look hard enough (or if I zoom using the browser feature), there is an underline. If I change the render to zoom by 300%, though, the underline is gone. Odd.

Comment: @arjafi I can confirm. With those two renderers the underline is visible but it's horribly positioned. So it looks like a bug.

Comment: It does seem to be an issue with MathJax.  I have started an [issue tracker](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1686) for it on GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

I'm seeing the underline running through the bottom part of the $k$ on Chrome, which makes it essentially invisible at normal resolution. I'm answering just to try out the possible workaround of specifying an increased exponent size:

$\binom nk = \frac{n^{\large{\underline k}}}{k!}$

`\binom nk = \frac{n^{\large{\underline k}}}{k!}` - still not highly visible but better

$\binom nk = \frac{n^{\Large{\underline k}}}{k!}$

`\binom nk = \frac{n^{\Large{\underline k}}}{k!}` - the underline is maybe now *too* separated but definitely visible.

Comment: You're right, if I zoom considerably I am able to see that the underline is actually there. It's just so thin.